# Symbolic computation using ``Reduce" does not give a result

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

Firstly, I have proved that `γ = β^2/12` is one of the solutions of `(A12 P312 + A13 P213 + A23 P123)/P123123 + A12 A13 A23==0`

```
γ = β^2/12;
l1 = 1/6 (Sqrt[β^2 ω1^2 - 12 γ ω1^2 - 
      12 k1^4 - 12 k1 ω1] - β ω1);
l2 = 1/6 (Sqrt[β^2 ω2^2 - 12 γ ω2^2 - 
      12 k2^4 - 12 k2 ω2] - β ω2);
l3 = 1/6 (Sqrt[β^2 ω3^2 - 12 γ ω3^2 - 
      12 k3^4 - 12 k3 ω3] - β ω3);
A12 = (2 γ ω1 ω2 + k2 (4 k1^3 + ω1) - 
   6 k1^2 k2^2 + 
   k1 (4 k2^3 + ω2) + β (l1 ω2 + l2 ω1) + 
   6 l1 l2)/(
  2 γ ω1 ω2 + k2 (4 k1^3 + ω1) + 
   6 k1^2 k2^2 + 
   k1 (4 k2^3 + ω2) + β (l1 ω2 + l2 ω1) + 
   6 l1 l2);
A13 = (2 γ ω1 ω3 + k3 (4 k1^3 + ω1) - 
   6 k1^2 k3^2 + 
   k1 (4 k3^3 + ω3) + β (l1 ω3 + l3 ω1) + 
   6 l1 l3)/(
  2 γ ω1 ω3 + k3 (4 k1^3 + ω1) + 
   6 k1^2 k3^2 + 
   k1 (4 k3^3 + ω3) + β (l1 ω3 + l3 ω1) + 
   6 l1 l3);
A23 = (2 γ ω2 ω3 + k3 (4 k2^3 + ω2) - 
   6 k2^2 k3^2 + 
   k2 (4 k3^3 + ω3) + β (l2 ω3 + l3 ω2) + 
   6 l2 l3)/(
  2 γ ω2 ω3 + k3 (4 k2^3 + ω2) + 
   6 k2^2 k3^2 + 
   k2 (4 k3^3 + ω3) + β (l2 ω3 + l3 ω2) + 
   6 l2 l3);
P312 = γ (-ω1 - ω2 + ω3)^2 + (-k1 - k2 + 
      k3) (-ω1 - ω2 + ω3) + (-k1 - k2 + 
     k3)^4 + β (-l1 - l2 + 
      l3) (-ω1 - ω2 + ω3) + 3 (-l1 - l2 + l3)^2;
P213 = γ (-ω1 + ω2 - ω3)^2 + (-k1 + k2 - 
      k3) (-ω1 + ω2 - ω3) + (-k1 + k2 - 
     k3)^4 + β (-l1 + l2 - 
      l3) (-ω1 + ω2 - ω3) + 3 (-l1 + l2 - l3)^2;
P123 = γ (ω1 - ω2 - ω3)^2 + (k1 - k2 - 
      k3) (ω1 - ω2 - ω3) + (k1 - k2 - 
     k3)^4 + β (l1 - l2 - 
      l3) (ω1 - ω2 - ω3) + 3 (l1 - l2 - l3)^2;
P123123 = γ (ω1 + ω2 + ω3)^2 + (k1 + k2 + 
      k3) (ω1 + ω2 + ω3) + (k1 + k2 + 
     k3)^4 + β (l1 + l2 + 
      l3) (ω1 + ω2 + ω3) + 3 (l1 + l2 + l3)^2;
Simplify[(A12 P312 + A13 P213 + A23 P123)/P123123 + A12 A13 A23 == 0]
```

Next, I want to solve the relation between β and γ through `Reduce`. However, it took too much time, and failed to give the output in finite time. How can I get the relation between β and γ?

```
ClearAll[β, γ]
l1 = 1/6 (Sqrt[β^2 ω1^2 - 12 γ ω1^2 - 
      12 k1^4 - 12 k1 ω1] - β ω1);
l2 = 1/6 (Sqrt[β^2 ω2^2 - 12 γ ω2^2 - 
      12 k2^4 - 12 k2 ω2] - β ω2);
l3 = 1/6 (Sqrt[β^2 ω3^2 - 12 γ ω3^2 - 
      12 k3^4 - 12 k3 ω3] - β ω3);
A12 = (2 γ ω1 ω2 + k2 (4 k1^3 + ω1) - 
   6 k1^2 k2^2 + 
   k1 (4 k2^3 + ω2) + β (l1 ω2 + l2 ω1) + 
   6 l1 l2)/(
  2 γ ω1 ω2 + k2 (4 k1^3 + ω1) + 
   6 k1^2 k2^2 + 
   k1 (4 k2^3 + ω2) + β (l1 ω2 + l2 ω1) + 
   6 l1 l2);
A13 = (2 γ ω1 ω3 + k3 (4 k1^3 + ω1) - 
   6 k1^2 k3^2 + 
   k1 (4 k3^3 + ω3) + β (l1 ω3 + l3 ω1) + 
   6 l1 l3)/(
  2 γ ω1 ω3 + k3 (4 k1^3 + ω1) + 
   6 k1^2 k3^2 + 
   k1 (4 k3^3 + ω3) + β (l1 ω3 + l3 ω1) + 
   6 l1 l3);
A23 = (2 γ ω2 ω3 + k3 (4 k2^3 + ω2) - 
   6 k2^2 k3^2 + 
   k2 (4 k3^3 + ω3) + β (l2 ω3 + l3 ω2) + 
   6 l2 l3)/(
  2 γ ω2 ω3 + k3 (4 k2^3 + ω2) + 
   6 k2^2 k3^2 + 
   k2 (4 k3^3 + ω3) + β (l2 ω3 + l3 ω2) + 
   6 l2 l3);
P312 = γ (-ω1 - ω2 + ω3)^2 + (-k1 - k2 + 
      k3) (-ω1 - ω2 + ω3) + (-k1 - k2 + 
     k3)^4 + β (-l1 - l2 + 
      l3) (-ω1 - ω2 + ω3) + 3 (-l1 - l2 + l3)^2;
P213 = γ (-ω1 + ω2 - ω3)^2 + (-k1 + k2 - 
      k3) (-ω1 + ω2 - ω3) + (-k1 + k2 - 
     k3)^4 + β (-l1 + l2 - 
      l3) (-ω1 + ω2 - ω3) + 3 (-l1 + l2 - l3)^2;
P123 = γ (ω1 - ω2 - ω3)^2 + (k1 - k2 - 
      k3) (ω1 - ω2 - ω3) + (k1 - k2 - 
     k3)^4 + β (l1 - l2 - 
      l3) (ω1 - ω2 - ω3) + 3 (l1 - l2 - l3)^2;
P123123 = γ (ω1 + ω2 + ω3)^2 + (k1 + k2 + 
      k3) (ω1 + ω2 + ω3) + (k1 + k2 + 
     k3)^4 + β (l1 + l2 + 
      l3) (ω1 + ω2 + ω3) + 3 (l1 + l2 + l3)^2;
Reduce[(A12 P312 + A13 P213 + A23 P123)/P123123 + A12 A13 A23 == 
  0, {β, γ}, Reals]
```

This question has also been posted at the [Wolfram Community Site](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3006865?p_p_auth=y6TDU1kF).